# Prove that $\int_2^3 f(x) \,dx = \int_8^{11} f( \frac{t-2}{3} ) \,dt$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_2^3 f(x) \,dx =  \int_8^{11} f\left(  \frac{t-2}{3}  \right) \,dt$$

This is a true or false exercise. What I did is this.

$$x =  \frac{t - 2}{3},\quad dx =  \frac{1}{3},\quad 3\,dx = dt,$$

Then

$$\int_8^{11} f\left(  \frac{t-2}{3}  \right) \,dt = 3 \int_2^3 x f(x) \,dx$$

Is this ok? Is this false? I'm not sure if I should do something else to prove it.

Comment: Formatting note:  surround mathematical expressions with $s

Comment: I think you also have a factor of $x$ multiplying $f(x)$, which should not be there.

Comment: It is false as shown by your substitution. You made two mistakes in your substitution: $dx=\frac{dt}{3}$ and the last integral should be $3\int_2^3 f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: It was my first time using Latex format. But that was what I was trying to write hah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $I:= \int_8^{11} f(\frac{t-2}{3})~dt$. Using the change of variables $x = \frac{t-2}{3}$ we deduce that
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_8^{11} f(\frac{t-2}{3})~dt \\
  &=  3\int_2^3 f(x)~dx.
\end{align*}
So the relation you stated is false (missing a multiplicative factor "3" in front).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have any example of this kind of exercise so I was sure if that was it.